# Make changes to a cached model with associations

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a model that is fetched from Repo and has some associations preloaded. I make to maintain this large structure in a GenServer but persist changes to it.  How can I persist those changes? For example:

```
query = from e in Empire,
        where: e.user_id == ^user.id,
        preload: [:board, {:board, [{:tiles, [:system]}]}]
empire = Repo.one(query)
#=> %Empire{
  id: 1,
  currency: 1000,
  board: %Board{
    empire_id: 1,
    tiles: [
      %Tile{
        id: 1,
        system: %System{
          id: 1,
          tile_id: 1,
          ore: 10
        }
      },
      %Tile{
        id: 2,
        system: nil
      }
    ]
  }
}

changed_empire = Empire.move_system(empire)
#=> %Empire{
  id: 1,
  currency: 500, #changed
  board: %Board{
    empire_id: 1,
    tiles: [
      %Tile{
        id: 1,
        system: nil #changed
        }
      },
      %Tile{
        id: 2,
        system: %System{
          id: 1,
          tile_id: 2, #changed
          ore: 5 #changed
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice that the system has moved from one Tile to another and the Empires currency has changed. Changes can include the adding or removing of associations. All of this is done without any data from a client so there's no worry of bad data being added as the server is the sole authority on how to manipulate the models.

I can't rely on the normal

```
changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
  model
  |> cast(params, [])
end
```

because params will be structs. I can try using change like suggested with

```
update_change(struct) do
  struct
  |> change()
  |> validate()
end
```

but now I have the issue of associated structs needing to be manually sent to their own update_change function.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this without adding all the extra complexity that I seem to be running into?

Comment: You can try `Ecto.Changeset.change/2` https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#change/2

Comment: I would still like to perform validations. change/2 seems to skip them.

Comment: The second parameter cannot be a struct but map of params. If you have a struct and want to convert it, Map.from_struct should do the trick.

Comment: @ChristianDiLorenzo I am considering this. The only issue is I would need to run through every association through Map.from_struct. But so far that seems to be the easiest way to go about it atm.

Comment: Don't worry, it has no side effects. :-)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the comments I was able to solve my question. I created a small helper module that goes through all the data and calls Map.from_struct on it. This combined with the regular cast/3 gives me the results I expect.

Here's the helper:

```
defmodule RepoHelper do
  def from_struct(struct) when is_map(struct) do
    from(struct)
  end

  defp from(struct = %{__struct__: _}) do
    Enum.reduce(Map.to_list(struct), struct, fn {key, val}, acc ->
      Map.put(acc, key, from(val))
    end)
    |> Map.from_struct()
  end

  defp from(map) when is_map(map) do
    Enum.reduce Map.to_list(map), map, fn {key, val}, acc ->
      Map.put(acc, key, from(val))
    end
  end

  defp from(list) when is_list(list) do
    Enum.map list, fn item -> from(item) end
  end

  defp from(value), do: value
end
```